# Django: Adding attachment to generic.DetailView

Tags: django, django-views

I have a existing Django App with a detailview for UserProfiles. Now our client wants to have the ability to 'download' the information of the page to a PDF.

I have added a button in the HTML to trigger the 'generate-attachement' method

```
<div class="input-group">
        <button name='zip' value="True" type="submit">Get report</button>
</div>
```

I have also added a 'generate_pdf' method to the view, which is triggered by the button above.

```
class ProfileView(ProfileMixin, generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'user/profile/detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.context.profile_user    

    def generate_pdf(self):
        from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas    
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['pdf'] = 'attachment; filename="summary.pdf"'
        p = canvas.Canvas(response)
        p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
        p.showPage()
        p.save()
        print(p)
        return response    

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        #Check if 'get attachement' button has been pressed
        if self.request.GET.get('zip', None):
            self.generate_pdf()


        #Code to load relevant data form a large number of models
        #append it to the 'data' variable . 
        #(e.g data['group_year] = ...etc

        return data
```

However, when I run this code / press the button the method / print commands are all triggered, but no attachment is returned to the browser

```
<reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas instance at 0x112165638>
[08/Feb/2018 12:30:08] "GET /user/profile/459/?zip=True HTTP/1.1" 200 41749
```

Yet I got most of the code from [the official Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/outputting-pdf/#install-reportlab), so its not entirely clear to me why my code is failing.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call your generate_pdf method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `get()` method of your view to customize response:

```
class ProfileView(ProfileMixin, generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'user/profile/detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Check if 'get attachement' button has been pressed
        if self.request.GET.get('zip', None):
            return self.generate_pdf()
        return super(ProfileView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: get_context_method will get called from the GET request, so no need to customise that. Look at the get method here: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Comment: @wobbily_col yes, but results of get_context_data do not formed response. It returns context dict.  Django views must return response and response os class based view returned from get method.

Comment: True, there are a few things wrong in the example given.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you should have used 'Content-Disposition' rather than 'pdf' to add your file to the response.

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="summary.pdf"'
```